# There is an error in XML document (2, 2): Visual Studio, SSRS Project file errors (VS2015-VS2017)

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, ssrs-2016

I have a solution file that was developed with **`VS2015`**, and it has about 20 project files.  When we opened the file with **`VS2017`** a prompt appeared: "**The version of the report server project is not supported and the project must be upgraded**".  We chose to upgrade the project and commit the changes, and the solution/projects are now working in **`VS2017`**.

When I use **`VS2015`** and use version control to **`Update Solution to Latest Version`**, the file are retrieved but the project files do not load correctly; "**One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly.  Please see Output Window for more detials**". The Output when has a message for every project that says: "**There is an error in XML document (2, 2).**".  I tried to right-click the project and **`Reload Project`**, but it gives the same XML document (2,2) error message.  When I use version control to **`Update Solution to Specific Version (and choose the prior working version)`**, the project files still say "**(unavailable)**" but when I choose **`Reload Project`** the project then loads correctly.

I would like to know how to fix the files in VS2015.  And then ultimately I would like to make this work so that both VS2017 and VS2015 can make changes to the solution files (Projects .RPTPROJ, Datasource .RDS, Report .RDL, and so forth).

**Full Error Message**

> C:\Users\myUser\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\SSRS\Project_ssrs2016\Transportation\Transportation.rptproj
>   : error  : There is an error in XML document (2, 2).

### **Visual Studio Version Info**

(edited)

I tried using VS 2017 about 1 year ago.  It was working fine for about a week, and then one day the program would suddenly not launch giving me the error message: "Package management initialization failed: Access Denied."  According to to people on SO, the is a very common error with VS 2017, but it has been likely been fixed in newer versions: ([Package management initialization failed: Access Denied Error when opening Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955197/package-management-initialization-failed-access-denied-error-when-opening-visua))

Some of my colleagues use VS2017, but they don't use it for too many things.

```
--Mine
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
---------------------------------------------
--Collegue 1 (did the SSRS Project upgrade)
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 
Version 15.5.6
--Colleage 2 (also uses VS2015, but in the future will probably start using VS2017 more frequently)
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 
Version 15.7.1



|--VS Extension--       || VS2015       || VS2015 updated   ||  VS2017 (upgraded SSRS)    |
| Data Tools            || 14.0.61021.0 || 14.0.61707.300   || 15.1.61710.120 |
| Analysis Services     || 13.0.1701.8  || 14.0.806.134     || 14.0.1016.244  |
| Integration Services  || 13.0.1601.5  || 14.0.800.90      || 14.0.3002.92   |
| Reporting Services    || 13.0.1701.8  || 14.0.806.134     || 14.0.1016.233  |
```

### **Transportation.rptproj**

**VS2015 ORIG**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ToolsVersion="2.0">
  <State>$base64$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</State>
  <DataSources>
    <ProjectItem>
      <Name>Gmenu.rds</Name>
      <FullPath>Gmenu.rds</FullPath>
    </ProjectItem>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <ProjectItem>
      <Name>listWarehouse.rsd</Name>
      <FullPath>listWarehouse.rsd</FullPath>
    </ProjectItem>
  </DataSets>
  <Reports>
    <ProjectItem>
      <Name>Daily Yum Products Daily Traffic Report.rdl</Name>
      <FullPath>Daily Yum Products Daily Traffic Report.rdl</FullPath>
    </ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem>
      <Name>Load Comment Report.rdl</Name>
      <FullPath>Load Comment Report.rdl</FullPath>
    </ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem>
      <Name>Load Planning Worksheet.rdl</Name>
      <FullPath>Load Planning Worksheet.rdl</FullPath>
    </ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem>
      <Name>Loads Under Utilized Exceptions.rdl</Name>
      <FullPath>Loads Under Utilized Exceptions.rdl</FullPath>
    </ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem>
      <Name>Orders for Load Building.rdl</Name>
      <FullPath>Orders for Load Building.rdl</FullPath>
    </ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem>
      <Name>Transportation Order History.rdl</Name>
      <FullPath>Transportation Order History.rdl</FullPath>
    </ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem>
      <Name>Weekly Loads Shipped Detail.rdl</Name>
      <FullPath>Weekly Loads Shipped Detail.rdl</FullPath>
    </ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem>
      <Name>Weekly Yum Products Daily Traffic Report.rdl</Name>
      <FullPath>Weekly Yum Products Daily Traffic Report.rdl</FullPath>
    </ProjectItem>
  </Reports>
  <Configurations>
    <Configuration>
      <Name>Debug</Name>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
      <Options>
        <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
        <TargetServerVersion>SSRS2016</TargetServerVersion>
        <TargetServerURL>http://gcod049/ReportServer</TargetServerURL>
        <TargetFolder>/Transportation</TargetFolder>
        <TargetDataSourceFolder>/Data Sources/01-DEV</TargetDataSourceFolder>
        <TargetDatasetFolder>Datasets</TargetDatasetFolder>
        <TargetReportPartFolder>Report Parts</TargetReportPartFolder>
      </Options>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration>
      <Name>DebugLocal</Name>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
      <Options>
        <OutputPath>bin\DebugLocal</OutputPath>
        <TargetServerVersion>SSRS2016</TargetServerVersion>
        <TargetServerURL>http://localhost/reportserver</TargetServerURL>
        <TargetFolder>Transportation</TargetFolder>
        <TargetDataSourceFolder>Data Sources</TargetDataSourceFolder>
        <TargetDatasetFolder>Datasets</TargetDatasetFolder>
        <TargetReportPartFolder>Report Parts</TargetReportPartFolder>
      </Options>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration>
      <Name>Release</Name>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
      <Options>
        <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
        <TargetServerVersion>SSRS2016</TargetServerVersion>
        <TargetServerURL>http://localhost/reportserver</TargetServerURL>
        <TargetFolder>Transportation</TargetFolder>
        <TargetDataSourceFolder>Data Sources</TargetDataSourceFolder>
        <TargetDatasetFolder>Datasets</TargetDatasetFolder>
        <TargetReportPartFolder>Report Parts</TargetReportPartFolder>
      </Options>
    </Configuration>
  </Configurations>
</Project>
```

**VS2017 UPGRADE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <FullPath>Debug</FullPath>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <ErrorLevel>2</ErrorLevel>
    <OverwriteDatasets>False</OverwriteDatasets>
    <OverwriteDataSources>False</OverwriteDataSources>
    <TargetServerVersion>SSRS2016</TargetServerVersion>
    <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    <TargetReportFolder>/Transportation</TargetReportFolder>
    <TargetDatasetFolder>Datasets</TargetDatasetFolder>
    <TargetDatasourceFolder>/Data Sources/01-DEV</TargetDatasourceFolder>
    <TargetReportPartFolder>Report Parts</TargetReportPartFolder>
    <TargetServerURL>http://gcod049/ReportServer</TargetServerURL>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'DebugLocal' ">
    <FullPath>DebugLocal</FullPath>
    <OutputPath>bin\DebugLocal</OutputPath>
    <ErrorLevel>2</ErrorLevel>
    <OverwriteDatasets>False</OverwriteDatasets>
    <OverwriteDataSources>False</OverwriteDataSources>
    <TargetServerVersion>SSRS2016</TargetServerVersion>
    <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    <TargetReportFolder>Transportation</TargetReportFolder>
    <TargetDatasetFolder>Datasets</TargetDatasetFolder>
    <TargetDatasourceFolder>Data Sources</TargetDatasourceFolder>
    <TargetReportPartFolder>Report Parts</TargetReportPartFolder>
    <TargetServerURL>http://localhost/reportserver</TargetServerURL>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <FullPath>Release</FullPath>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <ErrorLevel>2</ErrorLevel>
    <OverwriteDatasets>False</OverwriteDatasets>
    <OverwriteDataSources>False</OverwriteDataSources>
    <TargetServerVersion>SSRS2016</TargetServerVersion>
    <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    <TargetReportFolder>Transportation</TargetReportFolder>
    <TargetDatasetFolder>Datasets</TargetDatasetFolder>
    <TargetDatasourceFolder>Data Sources</TargetDatasourceFolder>
    <TargetReportPartFolder>Report Parts</TargetReportPartFolder>
    <TargetServerURL>http://localhost/reportserver</TargetServerURL>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <State>$base64$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</State>
    <DataSources>@(DataSource)</DataSources>
    <DataSets>@(DataSet)</DataSets>
    <Reports>@(Report)</Reports>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DataSet Include="listWarehouse.rsd" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DataSource Include="Gmenu.rds" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Report Include="Daily Yum Products Daily Traffic Report.rdl" />
    <Report Include="Load Comment Report.rdl" />
    <Report Include="Load Planning Worksheet.rdl" />
    <Report Include="Loads Under Utilized Exceptions.rdl" />
    <Report Include="Orders for Load Building.rdl" />
    <Report Include="Transportation Order History.rdl" />
    <Report Include="Weekly Loads Shipped Detail.rdl" />
    <Report Include="Weekly Yum Products Daily Traffic Report.rdl" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Reporting Services\Microsoft.ReportingServices.MSBuilder.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: As far as I am ware you cannot open a VS2015 SSRS solution in VS2017 or the other way round. It does warning you of this during the upgrade (and makes a backup of the original by defaul)

Comment: @AlanSchofield - You *can* open the solution (.SLN) file-- but the project file (.RPTPROJ) is not compatible, due to the XLM file structure difference.  If you revert the project file, the rest of the solution works just fine for all the other files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers

> **I would like to know how to fix the files in VS2015**:

If you can retrieve the older 2015 .RPTPROJ project files (from source control) and overwrite the new 2017 project files, then the rest of the files will work.  For example-- [AnkhSvn undo/revert a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723745/ankhsvn-undo-revert-a-commit/51752055#51752055).

_

> **Ultimately, I would like to make this work so that both
>   VS2017 and VS2015 can make changes to the solution files (Projects
>   .RPTPROJ, Datasource .RDS, Report .RDL, and so forth)**:

Team development in SSRS with VS2015 and VS2017 is not possible (best as I can tell), due to project file XLM structure differences seen in my question post.  We chose to revert to the VS2015 format, and get our team on the 2015 version of VS and SSDT.  I have experienced some serious bugs with VS2017 ([Package management initialization failed: Access Denied Error when opening Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955197/package-management-initialization-failed-access-denied-error-when-opening-visua)), so we are going to put that upgrade off for now.

Answer (score 23):

I resolved the problem by deleting the MyProjectName.rptproj.user file

Comment: This worked for me as well, I also deleted any .data files in my project as I've found them to cause issues from time to time as well

Answer (score 15):

Try to delete *.rptproj.rsuser file and reload project. It works for Visual Studio 2019 as well.

Or just create new project and add exsting items (reports, data sources) inside it.

Comment: I had to delete *.rptproj.user and rptproj.vspscc

Answer (score 8):

The problem appears to be in the .suo and .csproj.user files that are left over from previous versions of Visual Studio.  Delete these files and then the SSRS project should load successfully in VS2017.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to open such projects with Visual Studio 2019 using the following extension:

[Microsoft Reporting Services Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio)

However, I met the same error as mentioned in the original post, which prevented loading the projects the first time around. The solution was to remove the whole project locally and re-fetch it from the source control - apparently some local temporary files are troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall a visual new or recent visual studio update, A NEW .net update or the new version of vs. That is what creates that problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).